# Editmesh: Toggle between all edge-loop boundaries when selecting?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Does anyone understand what Campbell means when he describes this new tool function?

https://developer.blender.org/rB276ef3b3b5192aad5c3e5e02c69246

> Description
>
> Editmesh: Toggle between all edge-loop boundaries when selecting
>
> Now Alt+RMB,RMB will select all connected boundaries.
>
> There are times when you just want to select an entire boundary loop
>   ignoring face topology, previously there was no way to do this.

I've tried several models with different topology and *Alt-RMB, RMB* does not do anything beyond what I would expect.  I also tried releasing the *Alt* before clicking the second time but that does what we've always come to expect.

Well anyways, if someone has some thoughts on this matter, please shed some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It selects connected edge loops which are not connected to anything else (boundary edges):

[image]

This only affects cases where the loop is on the edge of a non-closed part of the mesh. For example, if you try this on an extruded grid (with thickness), nothing will happen as there are no boundary edges on a manifold mesh.

It should also be noted that this doesn't seem to work with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? I can not make it work in 2.70 (hash: 19e627c).

Comment: @maddin45 You have to use a version later than the commit mentioned in the question. The latest buildbot should have it.

Comment: I've just started reviewing questions I've posted which have no Accepted solution.  It seems this one slipped by.