# Create walls from a plane?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I have a plane, as you can see below, that I would like to be the floor of a building.

How would I quickly create walls from all of the edges?

[image: My plane]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In edge select mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>*>Edge*), select all the outer edges and press <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to extrude along the Z axis:

[image]

In the above gif I used [the new boundary edge selection tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10735/599), which is currently only available in the [latest development builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599) (it will be in 2.71).

If you are using an older version, you can select the boundary edges like so:

1. Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. Press *3D view > Header > Select > Select Boundary Loop*:

   [image]

Comment: How'd you do the boundary loop selection for new builds.  I can't tell what you did from the screencast

Comment: Just press Alt+RMB on the edge twice (see [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10735/599)) The old method works fine on new builds too.

Comment: That works, thanks.  It's nice to see it there now.  It's a very appreciated addition to the selection tool.

Comment: Great approach and very helpful for newbies.